# Find the sum of the series $1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1.4.1}{1.2.3^4}+\frac{1.4.7.1}{1.2.3.3^6}+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series

$1+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1.4.1}{1.2.3^4}+\frac{1.4.7.1}{1.2.3.3^6}+...$

I cant guess the general term for this series.But i think this is a type of arithmeticogeometric progression

Comment: The numerator is clearly not obvious.

Comment: The denominators are $n!3^{2n}$.

Comment: You might check if the last 1 is redundant in the numerator, so that they are just $1, 1 \cdot 4, 1 \cdot 4 \cdot 7$, etc.

Comment: @Aravind, shouldn't the denominator be $(n-1)!3^2n $?

Comment: I mean to say $3$ to the power $2n$, not $3^2n $